# Adding content to an outer div by selecting internal href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this setup, how do I add NEW_CONTENT before the `Class1` div by targeting the `unique_URL_A`?

```
<div class="Class1">
<div class="Class2">
<a href="unique_URL_A">Link</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Class1">
<div class="Class2">
<a href="unique_URL_B">Link</a>
</div>
</div>`
```

---

This is what I've tried. But, of course, this adds the content before `<a>` and not before `Class1`...

```
$(".Class1 a[href*='unique url A']").before("<div>NEW_CONTENT</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because based on your selector, `$(".Class1 a[href*='unique url A']")`, the `.before()` method will of course prepend the content in front of the `<a>` element. The logic of your original code is therefore:

1. If `<a>` element's href attribute matches the unique URL A
2. And that it is a child of `.Class`
3. Then append new content in front of `<a>`

In order to append the new content in front of the `<div>` with the class `.Class1`, you will need to select the element itself instead, for example:

```
$(".Class1").has("a[href*='unique_URL_A']").before("<div>NEW_CONTENT</div>");
```

The revised logic will be:

1. If `.Class1` contains the child `<a>` element whose href attribute matches unique URL A
2. Append new content in front of `.Class1`

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/jmovct60/